# OpenType font not rendering properly on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, fonts, opentype

I'm working on a Ionic project, and for some reason the font we are using is not rendering properly in iOS (in Android it's working well). We used the @font-face rule in order to use the font. It works well if I switch to another font (I've tried with other truetype fonts).

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'font_title';
src:  url('../fonts/font_name.otf') format("opentype");
}
```

Here's an [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPIns.jpg) of what happens: The title should say "Notificación", but instead it shows "Notiffjcación". [This other image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZOcA.jpg) shows how instead of "..." it shows "%.", and you could also see the different color at the accent mark.
¿Can anybody tell me if there's a workaround for this issue or should we just use another font? ¿is this problem caused by the font or by the OS?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/. You can check if your font has been loaded.

Comment: it was loading, but showing different characters randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always convert the font online at:
https://onlinefontconverter.com/
and check if it works. Once done with conversion lets say to true type font. You can use it like this.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Tangerine';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Tangerine'), url('http://example.com/tangerine.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body {
  font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, changing the font to truetype fixed the errors.

Comment: No worries.. My Gratitude :)